# What is the correct way to do Float/number math inside a scrollview using a geometry reader

Tags: swift, swiftui

The SwiftUI auto layout with `Spacer()` is amazing, it is all you need most of the time. I the rare case where you need to tweak the width of a box depending on the screen size I understand the `GeometryReader` is the appropriate solution to handle variable screen sizes.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader

I have a specific problem where I want a box to be approximately 30% of the screen size, but with a minimum and maximum width (30% will look good on iPhones, but the content is inappropriately wide when rotated sideways or on an iPad.

So my question is, how do you do math inside a GeometryReader, I want to do something like this, which does not compile:

```
struct MyView: View {

var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        GeometryReader() { geometry in
            // Default width is 33% of scree nsize
            var boxWidth = geometry.size.width * 0.33
            if boxWidth < 105 {  // Cap minimum width of box
                boxWidth = 105
            }
            if boxWidth > 150 {  // Cap maximum width of box
                boxWidth = 150
            }
            HStack{
              // output the sub views with boxWidth
            }
      }
   }
}
```

The errors are:

```
MyView.swift:58:34: Only concrete types such as structs, enums and classes can conform to protocols
MyView.swift:58:34: Requirement from conditional conformance of '()?' to 'View'
```

I assume it doesnt compile because we dont normally want to do math inside of our view controllers, but in this case it seems appropriate. What is the best way to allow the box to flex but only up to a certain point? Maybe there is a much easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found *a* solution, but I dont know if it is the best solution for adding constraints to the width of a subview.

You can move the math to a function that takes the `geometry.size.width` parameter. So I added this function to the `MyView`:

```
func boxWidth(_ width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    var boxWidth = width * 0.33
    if boxWidth < 105 {
        boxWidth = 105
    }
    if boxWidth > 150 {
        boxWidth = 150
    }
    return boxWidth
}
```

Then you can do something like this inside the geometry reader:

```
HStack(alignment: .center){
    Spacer()
    SubView(boxWidth: tableWidth(geometry.size.width))
    Spacer()
    SubView(boxWidth: tableWidth(geometry.size.width))
    Spacer()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            GeometryReader() { geometry in
                createViews(geometry)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createViews(_ geo: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        var boxWidth = geo.size.width * 0.33
        if boxWidth < 105 {  // Cap minimum width of box
            boxWidth = 105
        }
        if boxWidth > 150 {  // Cap maximum width of box
            boxWidth = 150
        }
        
        return HStack {
            // use width in here
            
            Text("Testing")
                .frame(maxWidth: boxWidth)
                .border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension or view modifier.

Here is the example of the View extension.

```
extension View {
    func setBoxSize(size: CGSize) -> some View {
        var boxWidth = size.width * 0.33
        if boxWidth < 105 {
            boxWidth = 105
        }
        if boxWidth > 150 {
            boxWidth = 150
        }
        return self.frame(maxWidth: boxWidth)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentViewDemos: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            GeometryReader() { geometry in
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.blue).setBoxSize(size: geometry.size)
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.blue).setBoxSize(size: geometry.size)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```